# Need to modify this script to close other elements that are not active

Tags: jquery

I have three areas for different departments in the company.  On page load, the FIRST one opens automatically.  What I need is so if you scroll down and open another one, all others will close.  Effectively only allowing ONE area to be open at a time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.team-list-header').first().trigger("click");
  }, 1000);
  $('.team-list-wrapper').hide();
  $('.team-list-header ').on('click', function() {
    var pointer = '#' + $(this).data('view');
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass("tab-active");
    if (isActive) {
      $(pointer).hide();
      $(this).find('a.click').html('Expand<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>');
      $(this).find('h5 > a').html('<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>');
      $(this).removeClass("tab-active");
    } else {
      $(pointer).show();
      $(this).find('a.click').html('collapse<i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>');
      $(this).find('h5 > a').html('<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>');
      $(this).addClass("tab-active");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.team-list-wrapper').hide();
  
  //bind the click on all the headers like before, storing a
  //jQuery object of all the headers
  var $teamListHeaders = $('.team-list-header').on('click', function() {
    //find the header with the active tab, to get the previously selected one
    //filter out the "this" incase the user double clicks the same one
    var activeHeader = $teamListHeaders.not(this).filter('.tab-active');
    
    //if there is an active header that was not the same as "this",
    //toggle it off
    if (activeHeader) toggleTeamList(activeHeader);
    
    //toggle this header off or on
    toggleTeamList(this);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    //toggle on the first header after a second
    toggleTeamList($teamListHeaders.first());
  }, 1000);
  
  //refactored the toggle logic to a method that could be used in the
  //multiple places without having to proxy the logic through the DOM
  //by click triggers
  function toggleTeamList(header) {
    var $header = $(header);
    var $pointer = $('#' + $header.data('view'));
    
    if ($header.hasClass("tab-active")) {
      $pointer.hide();
      $header.find('a.click').html('Expand<i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>');
      $header.find('h5 > a').html('<i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>');
      $header.removeClass("tab-active");
    } else {
      $pointer.show();
      $header.find('a.click').html('collapse<i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>');
      $header.find('h5 > a').html('<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>');
      $header.addClass("tab-active");
    }
  }
});
```